# Linear map $M_{matrix} \mapsto v_{vector}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

In my algebra's workbook there is this exercise that I don't know how to approach ... so far I have only dealt with linear maps of the type $vector \mapsto vector  $, I've never seen $matrix \mapsto vector$.

let $H:M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R^{2}} $ a linear map defined as:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    r & s\\
    t & u\\
  \end{pmatrix} \mapsto (2r+t-u,s-2t).$$

find the matrix associated with $H$ with base

$B= \{ \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & -2\\
  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    -1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix} \} $ of $ M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$

and $B'=\{(0,-2),(-1,0) \}$ base of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vector space, it does not matter how the objects are ordered. Hence you can think of a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ just as a vector $(a,b,c,d)$ in this context.